# Issue Python code matching files

Tags: python

Recently with help of stackoverflow i came to know how to match text files using python now im facing some small problem with same code...it performs following task

Input to program is two text files
File 1

```
C1orf159

FAM79A

IGFBP2

RNF25
.

.

.

.
```

File 2

```
ACVR2B

CACNA1A

RNF25

IGF2

.

.

.
```

I wrote one python script to extract common words between these two files as follows

```
file1=open("f1.txt","r")
file2=open("f2.txt","r")
file3=open("overlap.txt","w")

list1=file1.readlines()
list2=file2.readlines()

for line1 in list1:
     for line2 in list2:
       if line1.strip() in line2.strip():
          print line2
      file3.write(line2)
```

this gives result as follows

```
RNF25

IGF2

.

.

.
```

But there is a problem in this output second word IGF2 is not there in file1...script is matching IGFBP2 from file1 with IFG2..meaning it is looking for patterns... I dont want this i want exact matches between two files..

Can anybody help to modify my script to get exact matches between two files...

Thanks
Ni

Comment: You should have already corrected the indentation of ``file3.write(line2)``. But above all, I don't see **'IGF2'** as being in **'IGFBP2'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `line1.strip() == line2.strip()`.  `in` in this case will match substrings.  You are after exact matches it sounds like.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for the intersection of the two files? That's

```
s1 = set(open("f1.txt", "r"))
s2 = set(open("f2.txt", "r"))

for ln in s1 & s2:
     file3.write(ln)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting sets to do what the OP wanted in the most effecient way possible